# How do I get 2 different width divs right next to each other in a row?

Tags: html, css, email

I need to have an email layout where it has a header, and in the body will be two divs where one is 2/3rds the width of the main container div, and the other right next to it that will be 1/3rd the total width.

I also would like to know if there's a trick for making vertical rules, similar to horizontal rules we classically see.

Here's the code I was told to try, but I am not getting two divs next to each other inside the main container div:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AUSA email</title>
</head>

<body style="font-family:sans-serif;"
      #wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#first {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#second {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}></style>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.</div>
    <div id="second">Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a Code Writing Service, please try by yourself and then post the code in your question, after that you'll surely find someone who will help you...

Comment: OK, I added the code I was trying.

Comment: Please take a moment to study how to build an html email. What you have is going to fail and until you understand why it's going to fail, we really cannot help you.

Comment: You're mixing up your CSS and your HTML.  They need to stay seperate for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're refering to setting the display to inline-block?

```
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#first {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#second {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Flexbox**

Here is a guide you should read.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

CSS

```
#wrapper {
width: 500px;
border: 1px solid black;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
#first {
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
#second {
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AUSA email</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="first">Sample text.</div>
<div id="second">Sample text.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```